# Testing IIS and Tomcat fails, How to solve it?

Tags: arcims

I'm installing and configuring arcims 9.3 and I have many problems with it. I followed all steps in ESRI article here (http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/35515), but I have a problem with step 8.

When I verify IIS and Tomcat were installed successfully, when I enter test URL in my browser:

```
http://localhost/examples/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample
```

An error occurs, HTTP 400 Bad Request. So what can I do about the issue, my OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

**msvcr71.dll** is [the issue](https://web.archive.org/web/20120421081432/http://geo.geek.nz/development/getting-tomcat-apache-to-run-on-microsoft-windows-7).

This ESRI guide is more relevant, though it is for ArcGIS 10.
http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38486

Comment: Hi my friend, i have failed all ways in windows7, i will try installing it in windows server 2008 r2, thank you Mapperz.

Comment: When i do verify iis with tomcat are work successfully, my browser receive an error(HTTP error 500) in windows server 2008 sp1. see this pic,[http://www.mediafire.com/i/?z73z35qpfblao0i].

Comment: any other solutions!!!!!